# Exclude First Post from Each Loop if Boolean is True

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Currently I'm looking to make a 'Featured' header showcase, this works perfectly - only bad thing is that it's also displaying all of the featured posts in the each loop. So you have a header showcase and then the exact same post straight underneath (looks a bit silly!)

I'm looking to **ONLY exclude the first post if 'featured == true'** from the each loop.

Currently I'm using

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <% next if post.featured == true %>
```

But this is excluding ALL posts where 'featured == true' whereas I want to just exclude the first post which matches this.

Thanks

Comment: What DB you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, get `@exclude_post` first in the controller which to be excluded
Then use that in `view` to check

```
@exclude_post_id = @posts.where(featured: true).first.id

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <% next if @exclude_post_id == post.id %>
```

Comment: You did 2 DB query, nothing win. Inside the #each, still all comparisons are have to be performed.. :D

Comment: But I am doing it in controller, where logic should be written, `where` query if you `explain` it will show you in this case query is querying only one row and time will be `0.0 sec`. Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: Nothing wrong. I meant to say if you can avoid the the condition tests,,, But the question.. By first post means what OP meant... There can be several scenarios to select the first featured post.. may be by id, date or whatever ...

Comment: This code is not showing any posts at all now in the index view?

Comment: @Jonathan I have asked you something,, Could you say it please ?

Comment: Currently SQlite, but moving to Postgres in Production

Comment: @Jonathan because the code is buggy.. `@exclude_post` is an object which is always **true**. And if `if` is passing the test and `next` is keep **skipping** .

Comment: @Sontya Working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude featured posts from `@posts` use something like this:

```
<% @posts.reject { |p| @featured_posts.include?(p) }.each do |post| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well do something like :

```
@posts = Post.where("id != ?", 
                     Post.where(featured: true).order(created_at).limit(1).first.id)
```

Now in your view :

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <% your code %>
```